# Problemas con dos autoload en PHP

Tags: php

Buenas estoy haciendo autoload sin framework o composer nada mas con php, entonces yo vi en un blog que se podia usar dos autoloads en una misma carpeta, pero cuando lo aplico para dos directorios me sale error me dice

> Warning: require_once(C:\xampp\htdocs\Practica1\OOP\ejercicio4/model/Controler\Controler.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\Practica1\OOP\ejercicio4\conexiones.php on line 6
>
> Warning: require_once(C:\xampp\htdocs\Practica1\OOP\ejercicio4/model/Controler\Controler.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\Practica1\OOP\ejercicio4\conexiones.php on line 6

Conexiones.php es el archivo donde hago los autoloads

```
function autoload($clase)
{
    $ruta = __DIR__.'/model/'.$clase.'.php';
    require_once $ruta;
}

function autoload2($clase)
{
    $ruta = __DIR__.'/'.$clase.'.php';
    require_once $ruta;
}

spl_autoload_register('autoload');
spl_autoload_register('autoload2');

$datos_db = ['dbname' => 'registro_estudiante', 'user' => 'root', 'pass' => ''];
extract($datos_db);
$conexionDB = new ConexionDB();
$conexion = $conexionDB->conexion($dbname, $user, $pass);

Controler\Controler::saludar();
```

Por cierto, si uso un solo autoload si me funciona pero con dos no puedo

Comment: lo que indica es que la rutas no estan bien, que hace esta funcion ? `spl_autoload_register('autoload');`

Comment: registra la funcion autoload para poder llamarlos despues

Comment: es una funcion predefina de php

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que agregar un condicional a tus `autoloads` para que si no encuentran el archivo no ejecuten el `require_once`. Por otro lado, hay que reemplazar los `\` del path a los archivos.

```php
function autoload($clase)
{
    $ruta = __DIR__.'/model/'.str_replace('\\', '/', $clase) . '.php';
    if (file_exists($ruta) {
        require_once $ruta;
    }
            
}

function autoload2($clase)
{
    $ruta = __DIR__.'/'.str_replace('\\', '/', $clase) . '.php'
    if (file_exists($ruta) {
        require_once $ruta;
    }
}
spl_autoload_register('autoload');
spl_autoload_register('autoload2');
```